# Get list of all azure policies assigned to a subscription using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-policy

I am new to Azure. I am trying to get the policies assigned to a subscription(1e1707b7-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-71feab4b911d) using powershell below. I am not getting the correct count of policies applied to that subscription.

```
Get-AzPolicyAssignment -Scope "/subscriptions/1e1707b7-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-71feab4b911d"
```

I think there is some problem with the scope. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be the correct command. Do you also include assignments coming from ancestors ? That might be the reason why you expect to see more than what you got from the command. Here it getting assignments from this specific scope only, not then one inherited from the parents (Management Groups).

You can do so using the `-IncludeDescendent` parameter - see [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azpolicyassignment?view=azps-6.6.0).

Comment: Thanks a ton. I am not including the assignments from ancestors. Now, I got the correct count. :)